# Field Calculator not showing some fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, fields-attributes

When I open my attribute table, click on a column, and select Field Calculator it opens and doesn't list all of the Fields in my attribute table. Why can't Field Calculator find these Fields?

Comment: Using ArcGIS? What version? Is it a shapefile, a feature class, what exactly? Are the fields hidden? Could you maybe post  a screen shot of your attribute table vs what you're seeing in the field calculator?

Comment: So definitely something is wrong with my software because if I close out of GIS and then start it up again then everything is fine. I also have to close out and restart the program every time I add a new field or delete a field or the changes won't show up. Thanks for trying anyway, maybe I'll just re-install GIS (I'm using 10.1)

Comment: I figured it out, it's something wrong with the software itself wherein I have to completely close out of GIS (10.1) and restart in order for any changes to fields to take effect.

Comment: I would try a reinstall. So if you add a field and it doesn't show up right away?

Comment: Have you tried using "Reload Cache" in the Attribute Table menu?

Comment: This sounds like an issue I recently ran into. The attribute table window wasn't refereshing properly when fields were added or removed, and so values from one field were appearing under another field's heading. Might be a bad shapefile. I didn't have to do much with it, but I did notice that closing the attribute window or starting/stopping an edit session would clear it up (no reinstall necessary). If you've tried Paul's answer, this might be a good next thing to check. Bad field names would be another.

Comment: You might want to try removing your normal.mxt file to see if that helps, before doing a full reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hidden fields in the attribute table, then they will not show up in Field Calculator. In the attribute table, go to `Table Options`, and then `Turn all Fields On`.

[image: attribute table]

The key to note here is "in other dialogs". If you hide them here, they will be invisible to most other tools, identify, export, etc.